# *ngFor With condition to display sub categories under categories

Tags: angular

I am trying to display subcategories under categories with JSON response in angular 2 APP. I am using ngIf for filter subcategories. ifparent_id not null its subcategory indicates in JSON string

Here is MY JSON STRING

```
[
  {
    "id": "15",
    "parent_id": null,
    "category": "Dress"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "parent_id": "15",
    "category": "Dress"
  },


  {
    "id": "19",
    "parent_id": null,
    "category": "Men"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "parent_id": "19",
    "category": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "31",
    "parent_id": "19",
    "category": "Shorts"
  }
]
```

TEMPLATE

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        <span *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
      {{category.category}}
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <span *ngFor="let subcategory of categories" *ngIf="subcategory.parent_id==category.id">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
       {{subcategory.category}}     
        </a>
         </span>
      </div>
      </li>
        </span>
      </ul>
```

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: I'm unable to get subcategories under categories using above code

Comment: As far as I know you can't use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` in the same element. Use `*ngIf` in a inner element inside the `*ngFor`.

Comment: developer033 is absolutely correct, thought I'd just throw a doc about this :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#one-per-element

Comment: Thank you..! got it.. it works

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ul class="menu_inline">
        <li class="menu">
            <div *ngFor="let category of category_list">
            <a>{{ category.name }}</a>
            <ul>
                <li><div *ngFor="let subcategory of subcategory_list" (click)="onSelects(subcategory)">
                <ng-container *ngIf="subcategory.category==category.id">
                <a>{{subcategory.name}}</a>
                </ng-container></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```